# How do I succinctly note the sum of $(n-1)+(n-2)+...$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, notation, summation

I was playing with numbers and wanted to see how many possible connections there are in a network of $n$ nodes. I found that the answer was equal to `the number of nodes minus one, plus the number of nodes minus two, until zero` because each node can connect to every other node ($n-1$ other nodes), but then since this is undirected, each subsequent node already defined that connection, so the second node can only connect to $n-2$ nodes.

So, a network of $5$ nodes has $10$ connections — $\quad4+3+2+1$.
This looks very similar to factorials, and I figured there was some simplified form for representing this. If not, how would I express this in sigma notation?

Forgive my ignorance and also note I've found that the interconnectivity of a network can be defined with $n(n-1)/2$ (or not divided by 2 for directed edges), and my question is about notation, not graphs.

Answer (score 6):

You want $$(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+(n-n)=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)\;,$$

which can be simplified to $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k$ (or to $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k$ if you insist on keeping the $0$ term).

Answer (score 6):

You have already noticed that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = n(n-1)/2$. Notice this is also the binomial coefficient: $\binom{n}{2}$.

The network you are describing is called a complete graph $K_{n}$. So the binomial coefficient counts the number of subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$ of size $2$. Notice each such subset is an edge.

Also, note that $\binom{n}{k}$ reads "n choose k", and $\binom{n}{k} = n!/k!(n-k)!$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k.
$$

Similarly $\displaystyle 1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+\cdots+n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2$, etc.  That is how the "$\displaystyle\sum$" notation is used.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i$$ where n was your number of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

This "factorial with adding" can be expressed with triangular numbers.

N-th triangular number is the sum of all whole numbers up to n. It's notation is $$T_{n}$$.

Therefore, the whole answer to your question:

$$T_{n}=\sum^{n}_{k=1}k=n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+1$$